# Python XLRD Get Column Values by Column Names into List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, xlrd

I have a xlsx file in which the data does not start at first row or column. It looks like this.

[image]

Only the column names are known here. The data ends whenever there is "**********" in first column. 
I need the output in a list of dictionaries, like below.

'ListOfDict':
    [ { 'A':1, 'B':'ABC', 'C':'Very Good', 'D':'Hardware', 'E':200.2 },
      { 'A':2, 'B':'DEF', 'C':'Not so good', 'D':'Software', 'E':100.1}]

I could figure out the column names. But could not get the values. Here is my code.

```
import xlrd
from itertools import product

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for row_index, col_index in product(xrange(ws.nrows), xrange(ws.ncols)):
    if ws.cell(row_index, col_index).value == 'A':
        print "({}, {})".format(row_index, col_index)
        break

key1 = [ws.cell(row_index, col_ind).value for col_ind in range(col_index, ws.ncols)]

val = [ws.cell(row_index + i, col_ind).value 
       for i in range(row_index + 1, ws.nrows) 
       for col_ind in range(col_index, ws.ncols)]
```

But that gives error "list index out of range"

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Please add the full error showing exactly what raised it. Also, can we assume the column names are in the first row?

Comment: Here is the error details:

File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/sheet.py", line 408, in cell
    self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
IndexError: list index out of range

About the second question: No, column names are not in the first row. Column names and data are in the middle in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the loop variable `i` is already the **row_index**, not the **offset**.

So you simply need to change the row index of the cell to take `i`:

```py
val = [ws.cell(i, col_ind).value 
       for i in range(row_index + 1, ws.nrows) 
       for col_ind in range(col_index, ws.ncols)]
```

Or alternatively fix the creation the offset:

```py
val = [ws.cell(row_index + i, col_ind).value 
       for i in range(1, ws.nrows - row_index) 
       for col_ind in range(col_index, ws.ncols)]
```

---

What I would do is first find the last row according to your condition. Then, with a nested loop, create the dictionaries. Something like:

```py
import xlrd
from itertools import product

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for row_index in xrange(ws.nrows):
    if ws.cell(row_index, 0).value == '**********':
        last_row = row_index
        break

for row_index, col_index in product(xrange(ws.nrows), xrange(ws.ncols)):
    if ws.cell(row_index, col_index).value == 'A':
        first_row, first_col = row_index, col_index
        print "({}, {})".format(row_index, col_index)
        break

list_of_dicts = []
for row in range(first_row+1, last_row):
    dict = {}
    for col in range(first_col, ws.ncols:
        key = ws.cell(first_row, col).value
        val = ws.cell(row, col).value
        dict[key] = val
    list_of_dicts.append(dict)
```

And in a much shorter, unreadable way (just for fun...):

```py
list_of_dicts = [{ws.cell(first_row, col).value: ws.cell(row, col).value for col in range(first_col, ws.ncols} for row in range(first_row+1, last_row)]
```

Comment: The list includes empty values. Also I do not want the list. I need a list of dictionaries  as I mentioned in the question. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I wanted.
There should be a closing parenthesis at  "for col in range(first_col, ws.ncols:" line. But that's ok. Thanks again.